# What are uppercase and lowercase letters in AWS Cognito password requirements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The AWS Cognito password requirements and allowed characters are listed here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html

It states (at this time):

These characters are allowed in passwords:

- uppercase and lowercase letters
- numbers
- the equals sign "="
- the plus sign "+"
- the special characters listed in the next section

...

And then you can set these also as requirements for what the password must contain.

But what is uppercase and lowercase letter here? It it ASCII7 with a-zA-Z? Or ASCII8? Some subset of Unicode? Any letter in Unicode by some criteria?

All the regexp I find seem to indicate only allowing a-Z but this does not seem very internationally friendly. Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

This will be just a simple [A-Z] unfortunately.

As from their [password requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html) it is uppercase letters, which generally is seen as A-Z.